# casting a subclass object as superclass

Tags: java, class, casting, subclass, superclass

I have some question about upcast/downcast.

I created an abstract super class Animal, subclass Dog and subclass BigDog. and I also give abstract method in Animal, and override it in Dog and BigDog.

```
abstract public class Animal {
    abstract public void greeting();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
   @Override
   public void greeting() {
      System.out.println("Woof!");
   }
}

public class BigDog extends Dog {
   @Override
   public void greeting() {
      System.out.println("Woow!");
   }
}
```

now my test code:

```
public class TestAnimal {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Animal animal2 = new Dog();
      Animal animal3 = new BigDog();

      // Downcast
      Dog dog2 = (Dog) animal2;               //cast Animal class to Dog class, legit
      BigDog bigDog2 = (BigDog) animal3;      //cast Animal to BigDog, legit;
      Dog dog3 = (Dog) animal3;               //Animal Class contains BigDog cast into Dog?
      dog2.greeting();
      dog3.greeting();                    //in which class the method is called?
   }
}
```

I understand the relationship between superclass/subclass and how cast works. My question is, however, can you cast a superclass into a specific subclass, knowing there's a class in between? for example, if I have an Animal class object contains a BigDog object, can I cast the object to Dog? what if there are methods in BigDog that do not exist in Dog?

in short, you can certainly say a superclass object is a subclass object, but why can you invert?

---

On second thought,

I'm guessing this: I'm asking JVM cast an Animal class reference to Dog and link the new Dog reference to the BigDog object, rather than really casting the BigDog object.

So I can invoke all Dog and Animal methods on that Dog reference (to BigDog), but none of the BigDog methods, unless it was overridden in BigDog.

What Java checks when invoking a method is: if the reference (DOG) has the reference, and if the object(BigDog) has an override. if not, Dog method is called, otherwise, BigDog method is called.

Can anyone confirm my guess?

Comment: The proper usage of the methods: `dog2.greeting();` and `dog3.greeting();` or add method `public void greeting(Animal animal);`. Then the source code will compile.

Comment: sorry guys copy and paste forgot to change parameters.

Comment: This is a good excample for static vs. dynamic type of a variable. There are several books/threads for that

Answer (score 2):

You can always cast to a specific subclass, unless the compiler is smart enough to know for certain that your cast is impossible.

The best way to cast to a subclass is to check if it can be done:

```
  if ( doggy instanceof BigDog ) {
      doSomethingWithBigdog( (BigDog) doggy );
  } else if ( doggy instanceof SmallDog ) {
      doSomethingWithSmalldog( (SmallDog) doggy );     
  } else {
     // Neither a big dog nor a small dog
  }

  ...

  private void doSomethingWithBigdog( BigDog dog ) {
    ...
  }

  private void doSomethingWithSmalldog( SmallDog dog ) {
    ...
  }
```

Keep in mind that casting is evil. Sometimes necessary, but often (not always) it can be designed away by implementing methods on the base class, or by not assigning a Dog to an Animal variable but to keep it a Dog.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method whose signature will match with these method calls :

```
dog2.greeting(dog3);
dog3.greeting(dog2);
```

so, Its pretty much a compilation failure.

You need to know about Dynamic Method Dispatch.

here are few links [1](http://www.java2all.com/1/1/11/56/Technology/CORE-JAVA/Inheritance/Dynamic-Method-Dispatch),[2](http://www.studytonight.com/java/dynamic-method-dispatch.php),[3](http://www.opengurukul.com/vlc/mod/page/view.php?id=1961) go through them.

Comment: my mistake when copy and paste. the original code has to methods.

Comment: ok. Go through the links that are there in the answer. The greeting() of which ever the object that dog reference is referring to will be called.

Answer (score 0):

`If I have an Animal class object contains a BigDog object, can I cast the object to Dog? what if there are methods in BigDog that do not exist in Dog?`.

**Simply you will get compiler error.Since you can't call a method that is not declared in parent and declared in child class using parent reference**

Answer (score 0):

First correct the source code, so it will compile. The proper usage of the methods: `dog2.greeting();` and `dog3.greeting();` or add method `public void greeting(Animal animal);`.

---

`dog3.greeting();` - invoking method `greeting()` for `dog3`. `dog3` has the same reference as `animal3`. `animal3` has reference of `BigDog` so method `greeting()` is invoked to the class `BigDog` and the output is `Woow!`

---

When you inherit `Dog` from class `Animal`, then class `Dog` have all methods from class `Animal`.